# Query an AND in a many-to-many table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I know that this is a relatively simple question, I just can't figure it out. I have three tables: `people`, `presentations`, and `people_presentations`. `people` and `presentations` both have ID columns, and `people_presentations` that has foreign keys to each of `people` and `presentations`.

For example:

people:

```
ID | Name
1  | John
2  | Ian
3  | Mike
```

presentations:

```
ID | Title
1  | A new hope
2  | The Empire Strikes Back
3  | Return of the Jedi
```

people_presentations:

```
people_ID | presentation_ID
        1 | 1
        2 | 1
        2 | 2
        1 | 3
        3 | 3
```

I am trying to select all presentation IDs where a specific subset of people is attached. For `OR`s this is relatively easy: `SELECT DISTINCT presentation_ID FROM people_presentations WHERE people_ID IN (1,2);`, but for the AND case... I just can't figure it out. This needs to work for N people, so I'd rather not have infinite `JOIN`s.

Comment: But `people_ID = 1 AND people_ID=2 ... AND people_ID=N` will give you no result. I think you need a `OR` so `IN` is a good solution

Comment: @DonKnacki, agreed that that will not give a result, which is why I was having an issue. But I need the case where I only get the presentations where person 1 and person 2 are both attached. It looks like this has been solved below, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter the table for the people that you want, group by presentation and set the condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT presentation_ID
FROM people_presentations
WHERE people_ID IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY presentation_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 -- the number of people
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=f0f3d325de04a8496147d16972612760).

Comment: This seems to be the answer. Thanks so much! I will accept the answer when I can.

Answer (score 0):

A fun way to do it is to (mis)use LISTAGG:

```
WITH cteAttendees
  AS (SELECT pp.PRESENTATION_ID,
             ',' || LISTAGG(pp.PEOPLE_ID, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY pp.PEOPLE_ID) || ',' AS ATTENDEES
  FROM PEOPLE_PRESENTATIONS pp
  GROUP BY pp.PRESENTATION_ID)
SELECT *
  FROM cteAttendees a
  WHERE a.ATTENDEES LIKE '%,1,%' AND
        a.ATTENDEES LIKE '%,2,%'
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a099683956769aa1f2010235b827ed8e)